# java linear regression in the logarithmic scale

Tags: java, jfreechart, regression

I have a set of 2 data vectors representing X and Y. I was able to plot them using JFreeChart both on a linear and a logarithmic scale. On the linear scale the curve is exponantial and on the logarithmic scale the curve appears to be linear. What I want to do is to calculate the parametrs a and b of the linear curve in the logarithmic scale.

I do understand regression in the linear domain, i can use least square method for that but how can i do it in the logarithmic domain? How can I do linear regression on the logarithmic representation of my curve?

Anyone can help by clarifying how can i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, nonlinear regression is not a feature of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org). From your description, it sounds like the data may be amenable to a [linearization transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression#Linearization), which would reduce the problem to a linear regression.

Comment: As the reference for "linearization transformation" notes, the errors will change.  So, linearly fitting log(y) to log(x) will not generally produce the same result as fitting y against x using a nonlinear regression function.  How much difference this involves will vary from situation to situation.

Comment: @Predictor: Thanks for amplifying on this. The enzyme kinetics example cited hails from an age when nonlinear regression was much more laborious than now. I'd welcome your recommendation of a suitable library.